# JPA: Own Annotation to bundle annotations for fields with same value

Tags: java, validation, jpa, annotations

I'm wondering how to write my own Annotation for fields which have the same annotations.

For example:

**old class:**

```
public class XXXEntity {

@NotNull  
@SomeAnnotation_0  
@SomeAnnotation_1  
@Size(max = 100)  
private String email_0;

@NotNull  
@SomeAnnotation_0  
@SomeAnnotation_1  
@Size(max = 100)  
private String email_1;

...
}
```

**desired class:**

```
public class XXXEntity {

@MyOwnAnnotation  
private String email_0;

@MyOwnAnnotation  
private String email_1;

...
}
```

Any hints?

Thanks
Jonny

Comment: I don't get how this is related to JPA. Are you earlier annotations JPA annotations or bean validation annotations, and how are the new annotations related to the old? Note - `@Size` and `@NOtNull` are bean validation annotations and could be used to validate entities, but they can be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`javax.validation` has [constraint composition](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.1/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#validator-customconstraints-compound). You can bundle all validation annotations into one, custom annotation. To copy the example from the docs:

```
@NotNull
@Size(min = 2, max = 14)
@CheckCase(CaseMode.UPPER)
@Target( { METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
@Documented
public @interface ValidLicensePlate { .. }
```

You can't do that for non-validation annotations, however.